# Movie with png images in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png

I have png images as alpha_water_10.png, alpha_water_20.png, upto alpha_water_2780.png. Now I want to make a movie with ffmpeg using this, but the `ffmpeg -r 30 -start_number 10 -i alpha_water_%04d.png -c:v libx264 volfrac1.mp4` seems to give the video but it is not in the ascending order. The images at lets stay 270 will be right after the 20th image.
Would anyone know its fix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use `_%d.png` (numbered 1, 2, 3, ...) instead of 4 digit zero padded `_%04d.png` (numbered 0001, 0002, 0003, ...) for the input.